# performance of indexOf() vs a function loop doing the same thing

Tags: c#, .net, performance

I wrote a small program using a custom indexOf function but wanted to dismiss it in favour of the system string.IndexOf() method.

But before I started refactoring I wrote a small test program out of curiosity to see just see how bad my function was behaving in comparison of system string.IndexOf()

what I observed was the fact that system string.IndexOf *seems to be* a magnitude slower than iterating a array.

```
Processing random random string at 1000000 characters.
Processing method 1 system string.IndexOf
index 999999 took 620036 ticks
Processing method 2 custom IndexOf
index 999999 took 130007 ticks
```

So my question is really; **Am I doing it wrong?** *Shouldn't a system function much faster than anything else I write in c#?*

**tl;dr**
*the test scenario*

first I set up some test data, filling a random string with some data

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
Random r = new Random(); 
string c = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZ0123456789";
long before;
long after; 
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i ++) sb.Append(c[r.Next(c.Length)]);
```

and then insert something at the end of the array that I want to search for, worst case scenario

```
int j = sb.Length - 1 ;                                   
sb[j] = '"';
```

**method 1: system string.IndexOf**

and then check how many ticks is used by system string.IndexOf()

```
before = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
index = text.IndexOf("\"");
after = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
```

**method 2:custom method**

and after that I run my custom code which is just a static function with a while loop iterating over a character array.

```
before = DateTime.Now.Ticks; 
index = IndexOf(text, 0, '"', '/'); 
after = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
```

Comment: At any rate, that's not how one benchmarks.

Comment: First off, you should be using `Stopwatch` for benchmarks - it has better resolution than `DateTime`.

Comment: How does your implementation of `IndexOf()` look?

Comment: Without showing the implementation of your version of `IndexOf`, we can't say if it is actually comparable to `String.IndexOf`. One thing to note is that the overload you're calling actually takes the current culture into account.

Comment: How often did you run your benchmarks?

Comment: @delnan agree, but it will give an indication

Comment: @Oded thanks! That was better!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the difference here is that when you're calling `String.IndexOf` you're using a string literal, and your custom function is using a character literal.

Without having seen your custom implementation, I'd guess the `String.IndexOf` method is more correct (locales, unicode, and all that stuff).

Comment: Technically, it's locale not local. I fixed that for you :)

Answer (score 7):

`String.IndexOf` also has an overload that accepts a `char` as parameter. Try this one. Your own implementation apparently uses a `char` not a `string`.

```
index = text.IndexOf('"');
```

---

You should repeat the tests several times. Sometimes the first run takes longer, because methods are jitted or because static members are initialized or things like that.

```
Test1();
Test2();
// start time
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    Test1();
    Test2();
}
// stop time
```

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing how your function works, there can be several things going on:

1) You are looking for a character with IndexAt vs a String lookup

2) To do a much more accurate comparison, put your search term in randomm locations and perform dozens of iterations of each.  It could be a WORST case your wins, but the libraries win the rest of the time

3) Of course, there's nothing saying that the library is optimized for every solution and you could very easily implement something faster.  Just look at LINQ to see that